# Thermofluid mechanics temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> A steel alloy specimen (mass $4\,\rm kg$) at $80\,\rm ^\circ C$ is submerged in water at $10\,\rm ^\circ C$. At thermal equilibrium state the temperature of the steel-water system is $40\,\rm ^\circ C$. Calculate the mass of the water used.
>
> The specific heat capacity of the steel alloy is $0.507\,\rm kJ\,kg^{-1}\,K^{-1}$ and that of water is $4.2\,\rm kJ\,kg^{-1}\,K^{-1}$.

Comment: Have you at least tried and work it out yourself? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: (4 kg)(40K)(0.507 kJ/kgK) = M*(30K)(4.2 kJ/kgK),
so
M = (4 kg)(4/3)(0.507/4.2)

Comment: is it right please ?

Comment: Check it against my solution.

Comment: @andselisk Please take it easy on edits to old, low-quality questions - editing questions bumps them to the top of the front page, and a stream of edits like this drowns out more interesting content (batches of ~5 or so are OK, more is seen as abusive). For several of your latest edits, the correct course of action should really be to flag for closure and move on.

Comment: But, @andselisk, your edits are pretty good. :-) If I can suggest, when editing newer posts, you might consider to also comment a note to the poster reminding them it's *their* work to properly format their post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $m$ is mass of steel, $T_s$ is temperature and $M$ is mass of water and $T_w$ is temperature, then in the absence of any heat losses the following heat energy balance applies:
$$mc_{p,s}T_f+Mc_{p,w}T_f=mc_{p,s}T_s+Mc_{p,w}T_w$$
Where $c_{p,s}$ and $c_{p,s}$ are the resp. specific heat capacities of steel and water and $T_f$ is the final temperature, after thermal equilibrium is achieved.

Solving for $M$, we get:

$$M=\frac{mc_{p,s}(T_s-T_f)}{c_{p,w}(T_f-T_w)}$$

Using OP's data we get:
$$M=0.64\:\mathrm{kg}$$